# How do I properly debug / fix this boot issue?

Tags: boot, grub2, root, initramfs, unetbootin

I'm attempting to do a fresh install of Ubuntu.  In both cases, the system fails to boot.  I've tried standard and recovery mode, using Ubuntu 16.04.1 and now 14.04.5.  My hope was that 14.04.5 might be more likely to boot since it's an older release and this machine is extremely limited.  In both cases, I get an error and I'm dropped into an "initramfs" shell.

The specs of the machine are as follows :

> Dell Inspiron 15, 3000 series
>
> - 4GB Single Channel DDR3L 1600MHz (4GBx1)
> - Intel Pentium Processor [N3540](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel%20Pentium%20N3540%20%40%202.16GHz) (2M Cache, up to 2.66 GHz)

I don't know anything about "initramfs" and am not quite sure how to begin debugging.  Can anyone help me?

[image]

I tried using [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/) to transform this to text, but unfortunately, I don't know anything about tesseract either.  I'll see if I can make progress there, but until then would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Have you tried to boot on other machines? Is your ISO file good (matches with checksum)?

Comment: Hi @Anwar :) The ISO files are both good, but I'm using `unetbootin` and USB to perform the install. I've been able to use the "LiveCD" capabilities of the OS, but after installation have this problem. Perhaps it's an unexpected state since the USB drive was removed?

Comment: Please try other usb creator software. And verify that this is not a problem of usb creation or iso by trying to boot in other machines

Comment: Hi @Anwar , thanks again for your help yesterday.  My sense is that this is a duplicate of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1552985 .  I'll write up my experience in an answer submission.